# Voltages around a loop

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I am taking the voltages sum around a loop and I reached the following equation. Do you see any problem with it?

[image: sum of voltages around a loop is zero]

vC is the voltage of the capacitor.

Comment: Isn't the voltage on **C** an integral of some kind?

Comment: I'll second @periblepsis question.  Hakam, are you trying to write the equation in the s-domain, or an equation with derivatives and integrals in *dt* ?

Comment: i am trying to create a space state model of the system.
why there should be an integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation seems incorrect because IB is incorrectly computed.

You have implied that iB = (vC-vB)/(rC+rS)
i.e., vC-vB = (iB * rC) + (iB * rS)
but, the current flowing in rC is not iB so, this cannot be true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
taking the voltage around the second loop suggests that   iB = ((vC-vB)/(rC+rS))+ rCiL/(rC+rS)
do you agree?

Comment: @hakamzoubi,   Agreed, this is correct